# как 'img_name' отправит в сервер?

Tags: yii

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);


    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

        $dir = $this->getFolder();
        $uploaded = false;
        $file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'img_name');

        $img_name = ($file->baseName.'.'.$file->extension);
         if($model->validate()) {
             $uploaded = $file->saveAs($dir.$img_name);
         }


        return $this->render('view',[
                'id' => $model->id,
                'model' => $model,
                'img_name' => $img_name,
                'uploaded' => $uploaded,
                'dir' => $dir,
            ]);


        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

изменил так но не получается

public function actionUpdate($id) 
{

```
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

        $dir = $this->getFolder();
        $uploaded = false;
        $file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'img_name');
        $img_name = (uniqid($file->baseName).'.'.$file->extension);
        $model->uploadFile($file, $img_name);

        if($model->validate()) {
             $uploaded = $file->saveAs($dir.$img_name);
        }

        return $this->render('view',[
                'id' => $model->id,
                'model' => $model,
                'uploaded' => $uploaded,
            ]);


        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
}
```